# system.php on my server is it virus

Tags: php

I found one file call `systems.php` on my server. Also, when I download my website from the server Windows Defender saying that my files has `BackDoor:PHP/Small.L` and `BackDoor:PHP/WebShell.A`. I don't know what to do and I fed of with it now.

Any suggestion.

Here is the link http://pastebin.com/pSXzABed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no longer have control of that server. Someone has put their own code onto there, and can run pretty much whatever they like, at will.

Your best course of action is to spin up a new webserver, copy any unique content (databases and any created content that does not exist elsewhere), and reinstall - with latest versions of software - onto a new machine, virus checking anything that you copy over.

Comment: How do that file harm to my server?

Comment: It introduced a backdor. With that backdoor the attacker can execute any code he wants on your server, completely taking control.

Answer (score 3):

You should definetly delete that file from your server before it does any more harm.

**But** the real question should be, how did that file end up on your server? Are you running any PHP applications on your server? Maybe Joomla or Wordpress?

You should update any and all of these applications to their newest version to avoid security holes in old versions.

Google has plenty of info on this virus!

Comment: WordPress website is hosted on that server

Comment: Google has many reports of Wordpress being vulnerable to this virus. Make a new server from scratch, install newest Wordpress and migrate the database.